# Button does not call function when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'd like a function t run when a button is clicked. It works fine when I approach it like so in the html body

```
<div type="button" id="decline" class="btn btn-danger mrs"></div>
```

However, I need it to work within the below code block, which is within a underscore.js  wrapper. At the moment the function won't execute using the below, I'd like to understand why? is the id in the wrong place?

```
$('#containerFriendsPending').empty();
_.each(friends, function(item) {
    var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
    wrapper.append('<div type="button" 
                         id="decline" 
                         class="btn btn-danger mrs">' + 
                   'Decline' + 
                   '</div>');
    $('#containerFriendsPending').append(wrapper);
});
```

Comment: Where do you call the function?

Comment: @onetwo12 No worries I've solved it and answered my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the code solution you posted will work the first time:

```
$('#decline').click(function() {
    Friendrequest_decline();
});
```

It will not work after the wrapper code is replaced, as per your answer. You must use `.on()` to delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#decline', function() {
    Friendrequest_decline();
});
```

or

```
$('#containerFriendsPending').on('click', '#decline', function() {
    Friendrequest_decline();
});
```

Eg:

[$(document).on('click', '#id', function() {}) vs $('#id').on('click', function(){})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879168/document-onclick-id-function-vs-id-onclick-function)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this myself.

The following needed to be added within the original question main code block

```
$('.decline').click(function() {
Friendrequest_decline();
});
```

So doing this works.

```
$('#containerFriendsPending').empty();
    _.each(friends, function(item) {
    var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
    wrapper.append('<div type="button" id="decline" class="btn btn-danger mrs">' + 'Decline' + '</div>');
    $('#containerFriendsPending').append(wrapper);

$('.decline').click(function() {
Friendrequest_decline();
});

                                });
```

Comment: Please note that you're creating multiple elements with the same `#decline` id. An id can only occur one time per page.

Comment: @isogram So I should use a class instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's what they were invented for :)

Comment: @isogram the only issue with using a class, is I dont think you can use two classes together? as per my updated answer the button now has two classes?

Comment: You can, separate them with spaces. See the `class="btn btn-danger mrs"`, those are already three separate classes. Just add "decline" to that list

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide the code that launches the click event it's hard to debug, but I'm going to assume it's actually the most common mistake that causes this problem: You are binding the click event before the element actually exists. That way, the browser will not know the new element also needs the click event.

Example:

```
$('.test').click(someFunction);
$('body').append( $('<div class="test">Click me!</div>');
```

This will not work, because the click event is bound first and the element is created later.

The jQuery `.on()` function can handle that by also watching for new elements that are created in the DOM:

```
$('body').on('click', '.test', someFunction);
$('body').append( $('<div class="test">Click me!</div>');
```

Now it will run `someFunction` successfully.