# Javascript - Difference between $(document).on("click", "selector", function ...); and $("selector").on("click", function ....);

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is difference between these two codes ?

```
$(document).on('click', '.close_modal_window', function(){
        alert("window closed");
    });
```

and

```
$('.close_modal_window').on('click', function(){
        alert("window closed");
    });
```

It took me long time to find out why I want able to close a modal window.
When I use code shown in the first example it works, the second one doesn't but I don't understand why.

Comment: you should be looking for the word *event delegation*, google is your partner now.

Comment: When your JS code is loaded, does the `.close_modal_window` element exist?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502646/should-i-be-using-document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you are putting on click event to document, not to the modal window itself. Reason your first block of code works is because it works even if you add elements dynamically later. If you want your second block of code to work as well, you need to make sure that you already have the HTML fully loaded before trying to add click event.

Check out [.on() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

The way I figure it for myself is that your first block of code is going to put click event on whole document.

- Each time you click somewhere it will try to do a match of which
  element was clicked.
- If you click somewhere random it will not fire function, but if you
  click on the .close_modal_window it will find a match on the selector
  and fire up function you have there.

Your second block of code does the same thing but differently.

- Second way is faster, because you don't watch for every
  single click on whole page and then do the matches.
- It will tie click function directly to .close_modal_window and will
  only fire up once you click on it.
- However in order for this to work you have to already have HTML for
  .close_modal_window on the page, then run this code.

Also in this case if you add more classes with same name, it will not work unless you run this part of code again, so you have to be careful if you plan on adding more HTML elements with same class and have the click working on it

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that the second version of your code only binds the click function to elements with a class of close_modal_window that are on the page when it loads. The first version of your code binds the click action to any element on the page that ever appears with the close_modal_window class, even if it appears dynamically after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Above are two examples with button's click event:

```
<button>click me</button>
```

Look the difference.

---

Here is an example with delegation:

http://jsfiddle.net/xtz1np6d/

and here one without delegation:

http://jsfiddle.net/ketme18a/

---

As you can see, elements created dinamically, aren't in the context when the function was created, and for that, they don't have any function assigned.

---

I super recommend this lecture: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

---

But be cautious, had one time that I used event delegation and it crushed my niceScroll-plugin in iPad.

Answer (score -1):

> `first` it works if you have static html which you write like
>
> `<div id="divID">My div</div>`
>
> `second` it works if you make/create dynamic html like
>   `var myDiv ='<div id="divID">My div</div>'`
>    and then you append it in some element like
>
> `$('#someid').append(myDiv )`
>   the second approach is called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)