# Remove Dynamic Table row in jQuery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make dynamic table with javascript that elements can be dynamically added and removed with it.
Now, the remove function doesn't work probably.

I've tried .parent().parent().remove();

.parents("tr").remove();

.closest("tr").remove();

but they don't work.

The code to append to table :

`$("table tbody").append("<tr><input type='hidden' name='label[]' value='" + $(".inputTitle").val() + "' /><input type='hidden' name='htmlText[]' value=\"" + html + "\" /><td>" + html + "</td><td>" + $(".inputTitle").val() + "</td><td>" + typeName + " ( " + crArabic + " )</td><td><a class='btn btn-danger deleteRow'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></tr>");`

The Removal Code :

```
$("table tbody tr").on("click", ".deleteRow", function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

The expected results to this is to add and remove table rows dynamically. However, the removing event isn't working.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".deleteRow", function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to read this SO answer [Difference between $(document).on(“click”, “selector”, function …); and $(“selector”).on(“click”, function …)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652067/javascript-difference-between-document-onclick-selector-function) and change your code to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteRow", function () { $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });
```

Comment: I'll check and tell.

Comment: I can't thank you enough.
You're a suuuuppeeeeeeeeer Genius

Comment: yw and happy coding