# Get access to the child of a div in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
function createPicItem(num) {
    $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("merchPic")
        .append($("<img/>")
                .attr("src", merch[num].picAdd)
               ).appendTo("#merchCatalog");
}//End of function CreatePicItem
//--------------------------------------------------
$("#merchCatalog div.merchPic").click(function () {
    alert($(this+">img").attr("src"));
});
```

When the div is clicked I want to alert the src of its inner image.

But when I click it nothing happens... even the alert dialog does not pop up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Wow** is your original indentation misleading. Barmar has helpfully cleaned it up for you.

Comment: I wonder if SO has statistics about how much time I spend editing compared to answering. :)

Comment: dear @Barmar I looked my question over again... What did u edit for me??... I didn't notice any change...Mention ur edit to me plz... Tnx :)

Comment: I cleaned up the indentation, just like I said in the editing comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `alert($(this).children("img").attr("src"));` This will search for image element in the first level of the div

Answer (score 0):

I used `find`. The difference between find and children is that find traverses down the DOM. There's not much in it here though so it doesn't matter (but there's an interesting discussion about the speed of the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery))

```
alert($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
```

This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6k57ow1/) shows it in action.

As has been suggested you could equally use `children`

```
alert($(this).children("img").attr("src"));
```

A few things to note though:

1. It's important that `createPicItem()` has run before you set up your click handler (`$("#merchCatalog div.merchPic").click`) because otherwise it won't have anything to attach to. A good solution can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879168/document-onclick-id-function-vs-id-onclick-function).
2. If you look at the console (developer tools) you will have noticed an error is thrown. The error tells you that your selector `$(this+">img")` doesn't work. The moral of the story, check the console!

Comment: Thank u so much for ur complete answer and explanation.:)