# Wordpress sending multiple AJAX requests on one click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My ajax function for saving post is making multiple requests, and i can't understand why. I tried searching for the duplicate elements, that may cause double clicking, but there is no duplicates. And sometimes it posts on ONE click 4 times

Here is the screenshot of multiple ajax post, when i click on `#order_save` button,

[image]

My `#order_save` button, when i search for the `order_save` in the DOM tree, the first match is this element. (original click element)

[image]

And the second match(2 of 2) for the `order_save` is at jquery code (which is normal)

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $(document).on('click','#order_save',function(){
        var order_title = $('#client-order-title').val();
        var order_comment = $('#client-comment').val();
        var order_date = $('#order_date_till').val();
        var price_input = $('#order_price').val();
        var order_price;
        var order_attachments = [];
        if($('#order_price_on_deal:checked').val() == 'foo') {
            order_price = 'foo';
        }else{
            order_price = price_input;
        }
        if(!order_title) {
            $('#client-order-title').addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#client-order-title').removeClass('has-error');
        }
        if(!order_comment) {
            $('#client-comment').addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#client-comment').removeClass('has-error');
        }
        $('#files_public .order-attachment').each(function() {
                var attachment_link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                var attachment_title = $(this).text();
                order_attachments.push({
                'file_url' : attachment_link,
                'file_name' : attachment_title
                });
        });                     

            $.ajax({ // Line 68 is here
                url: my_ajax.url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'action' : 'xx_order_saving',
                    'order_title' : order_title,
                    'order_comment' : order_comment,
                    'order_date' : order_date,
                    'order_price' : order_price,
                    'order_attachment' : order_attachments,
                    'order_type' : 'public_order'
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.html) {
                        $('#currentOrder').html(response.html);
                    }
                }
            })              

    });
});
```

PHP handler in my functions php (working fine)

```
function xx_order_saving() {
 // posting data here
 if($order_title && $order_comment) {
  $new_post_a = array(
      'post_type' => 'orders',
      'post_title' => $order_title,
      'post_status' => 'publish'
  );
  $new_order = wp_insert_post($new_post_a);
  if($new_order) {
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $new_order, 'post_name' => $new_order ) );
  } 
  $template_file = 'xxx-order-saved.php';
  ob_start();
  include(locate_template($template_file,false,false));
  $page_template = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $response['html'] = $page_template;
  wp_send_json($response);
 }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_xx_order_saving','xx_order_saving');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_xx_order_saving','xx_order_saving');
```

The template file with the jquery code above is loaded dynamically using this function

```
function load_frame() {
$option = $_POST['option'];
if($option){
    $template_file = 'xxxx-'.$option.'.php';
    ob_start();
    include(locate_template($template_file,false,false));
    $page_template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $response['html'] = $page_template;
    wp_send_json($response);            
  }
}
```

Sometimes it works just fine, sending one request, saving one post, sometimes it posts 4 or 2 times as shown in the screenshot above.

Here is what seems to cause the problem:

If there is `order-attachments`, for example one attachment it will send two requests (save two posts) if there is two attachments it will send One request, if there is three attachments it will send 4 requests, if there is 5 it sending One again. I just don't get it. Any help will be appreciated

```
<div id="files_public" class="form-group">
<span class="list-group-item order-attachment">Image.png
<a href="//Image.png">...</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please read it first

Comment: are there scripts inside `response.html`?

Comment: `$response['html'] = $page_template;` `response.html` contains "yes saved" string and that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`$(document).on("click", "#order_save", function () {`

to

`$("#order_save").click(function () {`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post comments to questions yet, I'm sorry.

Comment: the headers are equal, ty

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty sure the same script is run twice after only a single click. Look for other jQuery click events that may load during the Ajax call, including the file with the original click script.

Comment: If it will be like that, i would see what kind of function duplicates the ajax request in the console

Comment: You can try `$("#order_save").click();`

Comment: You might want to try changing `$(document).on("click", "#order_save", function () {` to `$("#order_save").on("click", function () {` or even `$("#order_save").click(function () {`. Checking for click events on #order_save for the entire document may result in multiple occurrences.

Comment: Audite Marlow can you please provide more info about `...the entire document may result in multiple occurrences...` when i use `$(document).on('click','element')...` i just changed it to `$('button').click()` and it stopped sending multiple times

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879168/document-onclick-id-function-vs-id-onclick-function#answer-14879213

Comment: madalin just read the question carefully please, stop spamming

Comment: Even if he had multiple instances with id "order_save", jQuery would only grab the first element with id "order_save".

Comment: My answer has been edited according to answer your question.

Comment: it worked, but i still does not get why, on `$(document).on('click','ele'` are causing duplicate request