# How can I retain a toggleClass event state after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Say I have the following HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="link grey">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="link grey">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click the link, have the background colour change and have that state retained on ajax success (ajax call happens when the link is clicked). But right now, on ajax success, the previous sate shows up.

On success, I'm calling the function which handles the event

```
function ajaxOnSuccess(data) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.link').toggleClass('grey');
  });
});
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mzg2zk48/**

Comment: Where's your ajax call?

Comment: there are two ways. first: reinit the eventlistener like calling a function after ajax call `function myFunction() { $('a').on('click', ..`. second: use `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(...` and catch the click event on document.

Comment: @Chris I think I'm doing the first method you mentioned here. I didn't understand the second.

Comment: You must assign a class name to the clicked element in the success response. Toggling an element will assign the class name to the element but this i not persistent, so after the success (maybe the page is reloaded, I don't know) and the element has no class attached to it. It will help if you post also your ajax call o we cn see how you are handle this.

Comment: may you like to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879168/document-onclick-id-function-vs-id-onclick-function) about event delegation. it's very practicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `javascript` should be like following. Hope this will help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        //ajax call goes here
        //ajax successs call ajaxOnSuccess(this) function
    });

    function ajaxOnSuccess(elm) {
        $(elm).closest('.link').toggleClass('grey');
    }  
});
```