# Input type button not working within table tds

Tags: jquery, html, button, html-table

I do refers to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/WTzKR/) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery) but this doesn't solve my problems. I'm well informed since I used CSP, onclick attribute is not working, thus I use jQuery .on('click') to get this done but still no satisfied results.
Here is the structure of my code(will include only codes related to this issues):-

**html**

```
<td><input value="Resend" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="resend_sms" name="resend_sms" type="button"></td>
```

**script**

```
$(function(){
            $('#resend_sms').on('click', function(e){
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        });
```

Above is the codes related. For your notice, this part of html is generated by server-side script. Again, I re-test the this guy but still no results upon clicked.

Comment: Use this $("[id$=resend_sms]")

Comment: @SarikaKoli thanks for this suggestion. However, I'm preferred [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43109026/7083302) solutions since it's working in my case. Kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your part of html is dynamic generated or it is generating from server side script:

Then use it like:

```
       $(function(){
            $(document).on('click','#resend_sms', function(e){
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        });
```

This will work.

Comment: Great! I used this answer & it's working. Do you mind if I would like to know the reason behind this? Just to improve my logical thinking on this kind of stuff. Thanks. =D

Comment: @WafieAli as all the jquery event are associated with the document so we have to use document method for dynamic added html. for more details you can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879168/document-onclick-id-function-vs-id-onclick-function

Comment: Thanks buddy for this sharing! I will keep this for future references.

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine. I just added the jquery file to your code

```js
$(function() {
  $('#resend_sms').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input value="Resend" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="resend_sms" name="resend_sms" type="button"></td>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap template & script calling as above already called in header file. anyway, kindly appreciated your helps.