# add <a> using jquery append with class but isnt working

Tags: jquery, css

i have a problem when,i add a link with a class="add-item" using append function in page,

this link added to page more than one times,thats mean i want add a list with mentioned link that when click on any of them run one function
when i add this link handwork to page isnt problem,but when i add link with jquery append my func isnt running

**please check below codes**
//add link

```
$temp.append("<li>" + $("input[name=title]").val() + "<a href='#' class= 'add-item' >(Add)</a><ul></ul>");
$(".add-item").click(function(){
some code ...
});
```

Comment: Could please give some specific code in codepen or jsfiddle. Then I think I can resolve your issue. 

Also try to find solution in w3schools.

Comment: You have to use `$(document).on("click",".add-item",function() {})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(document).on('click', '#id', function() {}) vs $('#id').on('click', function(){})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879168/document-onclick-id-function-vs-id-onclick-function)

Comment: thanks for all, my answer was $(document).on("click",".add-item",function() {})