# how to know which children element was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning jquery and I would like to know if there was a way to check what element inside that `.alphabet` div was clicked.
Is this the correct way to do it?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".alphabet", function() { 

 var id = $(this).children().attr('id');
  console.log(id); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alphabet">
  <a id="a">a</a>
  <a id="b">b</a>
  <a id="c">c</a>
  <a id="d">d</a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) returns all children of the selector. In your context, you'll get all of the links instead of the one that was clicked. Here's a demonstration:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".alphabet", function() {
  let $children = $(this).children();
  $children.each((k, item) => console.log(item.id));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alphabet">
  <a id="a">a</a>
  <a id="b">b</a>
  <a id="c">c</a>
  <a id="d">d</a>
</div>
```

One idea is to target the `<a>` tags instead of the `<div>`:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".alphabet a", function() {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alphabet">
  <a id="a">a</a>
  <a id="b">b</a>
  <a id="c">c</a>
  <a id="d">d</a>
</div>
```

Another idea is to use the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".alphabet", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alphabet">
  <a id="a">a</a>
  <a id="b">b</a>
  <a id="c">c</a>
  <a id="d">d</a>
</div>
```

Finally, unless the `.alphabet` element or its children are dynamically generated, [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is likely not necessary. You can bind the event handler directly to the link elements, like so:

```js
$('.alphabet a').on("click", function(e) {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alphabet">
  <a id="a">a</a>
  <a id="b">b</a>
  <a id="c">c</a>
  <a id="d">d</a>
</div>
```

Also see [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Add click event for the `<a>` tag.

```js
$('a').on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alphabet">
  <a id="a">a</a>
  <a id="b">b</a>
  <a id="c">c</a>
  <a id="d">d</a>
</div>
```

Comment: hi William,
thanks, but I would told to user the method : `$(document).on()` which is better nowadays, is this true?

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879168/document-onclick-id-function-vs-id-onclick-function

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct. You are add event listener to main `div`, so event will be triggered when you clicked to this `div` and no matter on which child element you are clicked. You need to add listener to each child element if you want to determine the target.